# Multiple directory make and specific file into there dirctory

Tags: python, for-loop, shutil

I wrote a code to create multiple folders and specific files into those folders using python.

I have 1920 images and all those images are associated with 20 images files, named as `frame01, frame02, frame03.... image96` (1 frame has a 20 image files).

How can i create a new folder and copy specific files into that created folders?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create directory

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

To copy file

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)
```

Just create a loop to copy check and create dir and then as per your condition copy the file using copyfile.

What error you are getting in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

To select and copy files based on the first few characters of the filename, (such as 'frame' or 'image'), see below:

```
import os
import shutil

exist_dir = 'exist/dir'
new_dir = 'new/dir'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(os.path.join(exist_dir+os.sep)):    
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.startswith('frame') or filename.startswith('image'): 
            folderandfile = os.sep.join([dirpath, filename])               
            folderandfilenew = os.sep.join([new_dir, filename])
            shutil.copy2(folderandfile, folderandfile1)
```